# Ajax response Not working in Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, json, codeigniter

I want to show `tick.png` image on clicking save button when data inserted in database successfully. My view file name is `insert_your_committee`, model is `users_model` & controller user
Here is my code of all there files:
My Script of my `insert_your_commitee` file, All console.log show correct result but success function is not working. What is the problem?

```
<script>
    function save_committee($c_id,$m_id,$start_date){
        console.log($c_id);
        console.log($m_id);
        console.log($start_date);
        var mid=$('#irnum'+$start_date).val();
        console.log("df"+mid);

        var url= "<?php echo site_url("user").'/ref_add';?>";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'json',
            data: {c_id:$c_id,m_id:$m_id,start_date:$start_date,irnum:mid},
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('#'+$start_date).show();
                $('#btn'+$start_date).hide();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

My Controller

```
public function ref_add()
    {
        $this->load->model('Users_model');

        $parms=$this->input->post();
        $c_id=$this->input->post('c_id');
        $m_id=$this->input->post('m_id');
        $s_dateparms=$this->input->post('start_date');
        $irnum=$this->input->post('irnum');

      $data_to_store = array(
            'Cid' =>$c_id,
            'Mid' =>$m_id,
            'Month' => $s_dateparms,
            'Year'=>$s_dateparms,
            'Ref_Number' =>$irnum,
          );
        $params=array();
        if ($this->users_model->add_ref($data_to_store)) {
            $params['status'] = TRUE;
        } else {
            $params['status'] = false;
    }
    $return["json"] = json_encode($params);
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

And Here is my model

```
function add_ref($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('reference', $data);
    $report = array();
    $report['error'] = $this->db->_error_number();
    $report['message'] = $this->db->_error_message();
    if($report !== 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does _success function is not working _ mean?

Comment: It means 
success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('#'+$start_date).show();
                $('#btn'+$start_date).hide();
            }

dosent show any response on clicking

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure, but in order to get ajax to work, I had to add `return false;` after the ajax call in the function.

In my case, I was using ajax for login and backend was in codeigniter.